# Initializing libevdev in python so that a device can have multiple tools working

Tags: python, driver, evdev

I have been working on a python based driver to bring back some functionality in some old tablets.

I am initialising as follows

```
dev.enable(libevdev.EV_REL.REL_X )
dev.enable(libevdev.EV_REL.REL_Y )
dev.enable(libevdev.INPUT_PROP_DIRECT)
dev.enable(libevdev.EV_KEY.BTN_TOOL_PEN)
dev.enable(libevdev.EV_KEY.BTN_TOOL_RUBBER)
dev.enable(libevdev.EV_KEY.BTN_TOOL_MOUSE)
dev.enable(libevdev.EV_KEY.BTN_STYLUS)
dev.enable(libevdev.EV_KEY.BTN_STYLUS2)
dev.enable(libevdev.EV_ABS.ABS_X,libevdev.InputAbsInfo(minimum=0, maximum=Xmax*10,resolution=1270))
dev.enable(libevdev.EV_ABS.ABS_Y,libevdev.InputAbsInfo(minimum=0, maximum=Ymax*10,resolution=1270))
dev.enable(libevdev.EV_ABS.ABS_PRESSURE,libevdev.InputAbsInfo(0,254))
dev.enable(libevdev.EV_ABS.ABS_TILT_X,libevdev.InputAbsInfo(minimum=-64, maximum=64))
dev.enable(libevdev.EV_ABS.ABS_TILT_Y,libevdev.InputAbsInfo(minimum=-64, maximum=64))
dev.enable(libevdev.EV_KEY.BTN_LEFT)
dev.enable(libevdev.EV_KEY.BTN_RIGHT)


uinput = dev.create_uinput_device()
```

However when

```
[InputEvent(EV_KEY, BTN_TOOL_MOUSE, 1), InputEvent(EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0)]
```

is sent, a pen and not a mouse is listed in xinput
after this, although subsequent

```
[InputEvent(EV_KEY, BTN_TOOL_PEN, 1), InputEvent(EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0)]
```

work, positional data sent is ignored after setting the input tool to mouse again.

only the Pen and eraser work.
Am I initializing this wrong somehow ?
tested on Ubuntu 20 and FreeBSD 12

Comment: Please change the title into a specific question. Your question is buried in the last sentence and so you might not attract the attention that you need.